# Require help with multiple lights in EEVEE creating a clean and sharp black/white shading (shadows and light bounce)

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, light, shadows

I'm currently trying out different things for an animation series I've planned and need help with creating sharp and clean black/white shadows and light bounces, when the range of - for example - two (or more) point lights overlap (while casting shadow and light onto a ground). The scene contains a simple plane for the ground floor, an actor and two point lights, which are positioned in front and behind the actor.

I have here two pictures (four with the node setups), that I hope will illustrate, what I'm going for.

**First example (not what I'm going for, just to illustrate certain points):**

The first one is with the ground plane having a simple diffuse shader. As you can see, the two point lights cast two seperate shadows onto the ground while also lighting the ground corresponding to their position. A little "specular" overlay of white can be seen especially on the right side (which overlays the shadow). I would like to remove this little speck, but keep the lighting of the ground itself (can be seen much better in the second example):
[image]
[image]

**Second example (what I'm going for, but with the adjustments I mention below):**
As you can see, for the floor I want to go for a clean break of black and white. The two point lights cast again two shadows and also light the floor in a sharp circular form. But also here, there are those two "specular" specks which completely overlay both shadows (or, the "speck" from the one point light overlays over the shadow from the other point light).
[image]
[image]

What I want is to be able to use multiple point lights in this way, which each can cast their shadows and the "specular" circle not to overlap any shadows (but still keep the usual circle of light)
Specular is disabled on both point lights, though I think I would have to include the removal of that somehow in the material nodes of the ground material, though I can't figure out how.

I hope you can help me somehow. Should the description of my request not be clear, please say so, and I'll try to edit the question, to make it clearer.

I'll include my test blend file (with packaged resources), so that anyone who wants to help, can take a look at every parameter and my setup.-
Thank you very much in advance.

*.blend file: https://drive.infomaniak.com/app/share/139668/5c09308a-4b00-4600-925d-ec3cdd494f07*

**Edit 24.04.21:**

It is possible to render on different render layers, as soon as I have more than one light that illuminate the same region, which will probably be a common ocurrance. It is possible, but I would rather do it directly, if that's possible.